# FileSystemNotFoundException: Provider "jndi" not installed

Tags: java, file, jsp, jndi

I have this JSP code that I'm trying to run to read all lines from a .java  file. My directory tree looks like this:

```
| WebContent

- | resources

- - | Foobar.java (The file I need to read it's lines)

- jspfile.jsp (Where I'm running the code)
```

My code:

```
String.join("\n", (String[])Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(getServletContext().getResource("/resources/Foobar.java").toURI()), Charset.defaultCharset()).toArray());
```

Whenever I try to run this I get this error:

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: Provider "jndi" not installed
    java.nio.file.Paths.get(Unknown Source)
```

I honestly have no idea what that means and I'd love some help

Comment: A resource is not a file, and a URL of a resource is not a filename. You can get the resource as a stream. Do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all, I wound up using this code:

```
public String readResource(String resource){
        try{
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/resources/"+resource)));
        String line = null;

        String data = "";
        while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            if(data!="")data+="\n";
            data+=line;
        }
        return data;
        }catch(IOException e){
            return "";
        }
    }
```

It works great!